# Ссылка на печать pdf документа

Tags: веб-программирование, pdf

На моем сайте есть ссылка, которая ведет на PDF файл. При нажатии, в браузере открывается сам файл. С помощью какого инструмента можно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку открывалось сразу окно печати этого файла?